# ASP.NET MVC Identity not to use ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We are developing a web project where we are going to manage the user´s authentication apart from Identity. We want to use Identity because of the security framework it gives to us. As we have read, the recommendation is not to build your own authetication system but to use Identity.

The authentication itself is made against another database. That section is working well. We have replaced some code in the methods of the Account controller and the user can register, login, logout and reset her password.

The problem is that when the authentication cookie expire (you set the time in the ConfigureAuth method of the Startup partial class inside the Startup.Auth.cs file) we get an exception of a SQL Server that is not responding. In the development environment this is working because Visual Studio uses a LocalDB that "replace" the SQL Server but in the production environment we are not going to install a SQL Server.

I have been searching a lot in order to use another provider like in memory database instead of the SQL Server but I couldn´t make it work. We only get the E-mail of the user from te cookie to validate it so there will be nothing stored in the "Identity database" (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and all those tables).

Another alternative could be to recreate the Identity tables in our database and only replace the connection string ("DefaultConnection" in the ApplicationDbContext class) but it would contain no data. It will be great if we can tell Identity not to use persistance.

A workaround could be to "catch" all the errors in the Application_Error (inside Global.asax file) and redirect to login but the problem is that the website waits for the timeout to connect to the SQL Server before generating the error. This will only happend when the cookie has expired but this not a real solution for this issue.

Hope I´m clear enough describing the situation!

Comment: If you're not persisting the authentication model in a database, where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks for your instant comment @YuriyFaktorovich! We are doing the all the user validation logic inside the AccountController and getting the data from a MySQL database that has a different structure.

Comment: A. Shouldn't you then be deploying that MySql instance on DEV? B. How about injecting different repository providers based on the build or configuration setting.

Comment: A. Yes, I have that MySql instance in DEV and it´s working OK. I can login users, registers, logoff, etc. B. I don´t need another provider because we are not storing any data inside the MSSQL (Identity Database). Am I clear?

Comment: Nope super confusing. How can you do logins, registers, logoff if you're not storing anything?

Comment: Yes, I´m storing them in the MySQL database. I have edited the Login, register and logoff methods in the Account controller. For example, before calling SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...) in the Login method I check if the credentials are valid.

Comment: Perhaps, writing my own Authentication Filter could be a solution.

Comment: Right, Ignacio, the best approach would be to use Identity with your MySql database, no code changes at all. https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/03/20/csharp-dotnet-core-identity-mysql/